# Passing information from one form to another in same method

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I currently have two forms in my application. FormA and FormB. FormA has only one button in it called cmdAction. FormB has two checkboxes optionA and optionB and a save button in it.Now Here is what I am trying to achieve - once a user presses cmdAction in FormA , FormB pops up and the user has to select either of the two checkboxes or even both and then press the save button to continue. Once the save button is pressed the selection made by the user is passed back to the FormA which gets back focus (FormB has disappeared).
I wanted to know how I could achieve this in such a way that I could just pass a function name and that function returns which checkboxes have been checked.

I know I could achieve this by simply displaying FormB whenever cmdAction is clicked.And whenever the savebutton on FormB is clicked a method in formB is called which analyzes the status of the checkboxes and returns the result to another method on FormA.I wanted to know if there was a better and a cleaner way of achieving this

Comment: There are hundreds.. if not thousands of duplicates on SO...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would simply use delegates and pass a reference to the callback function into FormB.
http://www.akadia.com/services/dotnet_delegates_and_events.html